# Error while using functions in python (Discord.py)

Tags: python, function, discord, discord.py

I can't call function from another file.
My code:

```
def standard(title, desc, color):
    return color = embeds.colors. + color
    return embed=discord.Embed(title=title, description=desc, color=color)
    return embed.set_footer(text=embeds.settings.footer)
```

Error Code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\def75\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\def75\Desktop\discordbot\new\cogs\fun.py", line 22, in _8ball
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'embed' referenced before assignment

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\def75\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 903, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\def75\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 855, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\def75\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'embed' referenced before assignment

C:\Users\def75\Desktop\discordbot\new>python main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 4, in <module>
    from config import *
  File "C:\Users\def75\Desktop\discordbot\new\config.py", line 24
    return color = embeds.colors. + color
                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Whole function is in class: embeds.definitions. (Yeah those are two classes)

And this happens with any function

Comment: embeds needs to be in scope. Without more context, some possibilities: it must be imported, it must be referenced from another module or instance

Answer (score 0):

When you are using `return` function in the Python, you can't use it more then once in a function. `return` returns a value and quits the function.

Also you can't use `=` in `return` too. You can change your code like this:

```
def standard(title, desc, color):
    embed = discord.Embed(title=title, description=desc, color=color)
    embed.set_footer(text=embeds.settings.footer)
    return embed
```

Comment: There can't be a syntax error in the code that I've sended. Which line do you getting the error?

Answer (score 0):

This is a syntax error indeed. You are `returning` an assignment

```
return x = y
```

`x = y` doesn't actually hold any value, instead it puts the value `y` inside of the variable `x`, so you can't `return` it (it `does` something, but doesn't `give` you anything).

I don't get why you are returning all of these things? You might wanna look into how `return` works.